Problems with esBuild and GraphQL
I am trying to package a project made with TypeScript, GraphQL and serverless, using esBuild. But it throws me an error, which wants me to add the "type" to all the @Column of my entities (I did them manually throughout the project)

ColumnTypeUndefinedError2: Column type for PromotionWinner#promotion_id is not defined and cannot be guessed. Make sure you have turned on an "emitDecoratorMetadata": true option in tsconfig.json. Also make sure you have imported "reflect-metadata" on top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity imported).
If you are using JavaScript instead of TypeScript you must explicitly provide a column type.

and now it wants me to do something similar for all the @args of my "resolvers", (that is if I don't want to do it manually)

Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript reflection system. You need to provide explicit type for argument named 'data' of 'updateCustomExpense' of 'xv' class.

Among the solutions that both the terminal and the internet suggested to me was to add the values ​​"emitDecoratorMetadata": true and "experimentalDecorators": true to my tsconfigure file, but it didn't help much, another solution was to add at the very beginning (in my case the handlers) "reflect-metadata", which was already added but was also being ignored, I would like to know if someone found a package or pluggin that has helped them solve this problem.
This is my esbuild.config.js file:
module.exports = (serverless) => ({
  target: "node20",
  bundle: true,
  sourcemap: true,
  minify: true,
  platform: "node",
  external: ["lodash", "reflect-metadata"],
  plugins: [],
  exclude: ["aws-sdk"],
  packagePath: "./package.json",
  tsconfig: "tsconfig.json",
  inject: ["./node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"],
});

This is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "module": "ES2022",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "outDir": "build",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,               
    "strictNullChecks": false,            
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    ".serverless/**/*",
    ".webpack/**/*",
    "_warmup/**/*",
    ".vscode/**/*",
    "./**/*.spec.ts",
    "__tests__",
    "__integration_tests__",
    "__tests__",
    "__testsResponses__"
  ]
}

serverless.yml, custom:
custom: 
    esbuild:
        config: './esbuild.config.js'

Package versions:
"reflect-metadata": "^0.2.2",
"serverless-esbuild": "^1.54.5",
"serverless": "^3.39.0",
"esbuild": "^0.24.0",

